# add comment to a folder or file

Tags: directory

how can i add comment to a folder or file that is visible all the time. (help me find the desired folder without opening it).
Comments like...
Ticket to patna.
Old prescriptions which are no longer required.
Kapil sir, who was in old office.
Report prior to ammendment...
It is very difficult to open each Folder/PDF/excel/word to find the desired one. so i want to add comment to a file/folder that briefly describes what is inside without clicking. it will be great help if comment are searchable.

Comment: Can you not rename the folder to the desired "comment"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File browser with tags to organize documents](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868430/file-browser-with-tags-to-organize-documents)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, Long name of folder is not convinient. in some cases I can rename, but i wanted some efficient way, or database type storage.

Comment: One way is to put a file named `README` (or `0README` starting with zero to make it list before other files) containing the comment you want into the folder, or name it `0-the-comment-you-want` to make it very easy to see the comment you want. Another way is to make a symbolic link named `0-the-comment-you-want` pointing to the target (works with files as well as folders).

Answer (score 1):

You essentially cannot, unfortunatelly. There is no provision to tag files with text. A workaround could be to create a "sidecar" text file starting with the name of the file, then including the comments, or including the comments within the file so they could be searched or displayed using terminal tools.

Work has been done to bring tags to nautilus, but that appears not to have realized. The former `tracker-tag` command line tool is not anymore available since Ubuntu 22.04.